# I need to save record in asp.net using Ajax. I think saveData() is not execute in ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to save record in asp.net c# using Ajax. I submit my two files named `addquestion.aspx` and `addquestion.aspx.cs`. There was no compilation error in code but record is not inserted in database.

**addquestion.aspx**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#submit").click(function()
        {
            alert("step1");
            var mcq = $("#question").val();
            var ans1 = $("#optiona").val();
            var ans2 = $("#optionb").val();
            var ans3 = $("#optionc").val();
            var ans4 = $("#optiond").val();
            var rightans = $("#rightans").val();

            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url : 'addquestion.aspx/saveData',
                data :  "{'mcq':'" + mcq + "','ans1':'" + ans1 + "','ans2':'" + ans2 + "','ans3':'" + ans3 + "','ans4':'" + ans4 + "','rightans':'" + rightans + "'}",
                success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
               }
```

**addquestion.aspx.cs**

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

```
public static string saveData(string mcq, string ans1,string ans2, string ans3, string ans4, string rightans)
{
   String connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    con.Open();
    String query = "select count(*) as totalrecord from mcq";
    int count = 0;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    if ((int)dr["totalrecord"] == 0)
        count = 1;
    else
        count = (int)dr["totalrecord"] + 1;
    dr.Close();
    query = "insert into mcq values (" + count + ",'" + mcq + "','" + ans1 + "'," + ans2 + "'," + ans3 + "','" + ans4 + "','" + rightans + "')";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    return "true";
}        
         });
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query = "insert into mcq values ...;
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
int ins = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

for insert value ExecuteReader is wrong its use for select record from database
for insert data u can use ExecuteNonQuery()
change it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get your debugger on first line of saveData method to make sure that its atleast getting inside codebehind function ?

Comment: it should be asked as comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert record into MCQ table, the better approach would be write a stored procedure to insert the records instead of writing in-line queries as you have done. And you can pass parameter to this stored procedure through C# code as shown below..

For example..

```
String connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ToString();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring );
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("your_insert_procedure_name");
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@mcq ', mcq );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@ans1 ', ans1 );
....
.....

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will insert new record into your mcq table.
If you wish to insert count as first field in mcq table, you can do that inside of your insert procedure.

First get total count of rows in the table and store in local variable, use this value wjhen you make the insert query.

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT
Select @COUNT=count(*) from mcq
// Perform insert query
```

Hope this helps you.